# Do scriptures say how to detect someone claiming a false varna identity?

Tags: caste-system

After all a so-called "low-caste" person could go somewhere else and claim to be of a "higher" caste.  Do scriptures talk about such cases and how to detect them?

Comment: There are too many similar questions about caste

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is what the Manusmriti says about how to find out the caste of someone whose parentage is unknown; meaning you want to know the caste he was born into but unable to do so because you don't know the caste of his parents, so you would then infer based on the behavior of the person.

[Verses 10.57 to 10.60:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201791.html)

> The man of impure origin, who is devoid of caste, unknown, a
>   non-Aryan, even though having the appearance of an Aryan,—one shall
>   discover by his acts.—(57)
>
> Snobbishness, harshness, cruelty, and proneness to neglect duties,
>   mark the man of impure origin in this world.—(58)
>
> The base-born man bears the character of his father, or of his mother,
>   or of both; he can never conceal his origin.—(59)
>
> Even when one is born in a great family, if there be a confusion
>   regarding his parentage, he surely imbibes the traits thereof, to a
>   greater or lesser extent.—(60)

Also,

> Viṣṇu (16.17).—‘All members of the mixed castes may be found out by their deeds, whether their descent has been kept secret or is generally known.’

Comment: Sir our Room was disabled. I have more doubts to ask
https://www.mid-day.com/articles/does-hindu-meal-include-dalit-food/23163200
How do we make Veg food available to everyone including Antyajs?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru They can buy from market or make their own meals right?

Comment: sir please dont mistake me. I am asking all this because I am really honestly willing to help them. In our Chilkur Balaji Temple(Hyderabad) The preists have hugged and welcomed Dalits. We are trying our best to help them
You said Market but how will chandalas earn money??Burning corpses etc hardly gets them money for all month...

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru That is an issue of acquiring food, not just vegetarian food, since I think meat and vegetables should be around the same price. But if they can't get enough money to eat food, then brahmins or someone will provide them food.

Comment: Sure na sir?There should have been some law na?Or make them small scale agricultural labourers?? And as MB says they sell decorative things in Market...??

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Yes, if they need money then they can take up other craftsmen jobs.

Comment: Sir so the conclusion is that whatever the Varna of the Jiva be it even an outcaste or whatever The society would somehow or the other ensure their safety that they were never mistreated and had enough acces to basic vegetarian/healthy food,shelter and resources. And purpose of human life is to explained by Lord in Gita and we just need to surrender to him. Today all this is irrelevant. Is this the conclusion sir ? But the kind of abuses we receive on Hinduism really shakes me off.....

Comment: Sir and Gita can be read by anyone. But Ramanujacharya and Shankaracharya quote Upanishadic verses there. So there's no harm if Sudras read those Upanishadic verses na?

Comment: Yes, regardless of caste, all members of society and their spiritual and physical needs would be taken care of by the king and brahmanas. "Today all this is irrelevant" - well surrendering to God is most certainly relevant today, but the varnashrama dharma institution is gone today and it's mostly irrelevant at the society level.

Comment: Gita can be read anyone, that is correct. Traditionally upanishads were never written down but chanted orally, and shudras would not learn about philosophy from upanishad verses but through lecture by brahmanas.

Comment: THanks a lot sir ! Sir Do I Irritate you with my doubts?Please tell sir! Please dont mind sir...Another doubt ..All 4 Varnas can do Shardhas(Including sudras without Vedic Mantras according to Smritis) and protect and help their ancestors go to heaven etc but why cant Chandalas do it to help their ancestors?

Comment: Sir don't Rebirth Karma and Shardha contradict among themselves? Our ancestors might have got rebirth or moksha. Either cases what's use of Shardha? I mean as a sign of admiration is good but...Really it protects and helps them??
Sir dont temporary heaven and hell and also birth as dog pig etc due to lower karma contradict?
Sir and few castes eating meat-you said its not sinful right because Vedas allow them to eat till a limit...?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru *Everyone* has to do shraddha as far as I'm aware, but if it's true that a chandala can't do it, then he may just not be able to *personally* do it, and in that case, a brahmana would do it on his behalf.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru I think there is a group of beings known as the "pitr devatas" that are "pitrs" for certain classes of beings. These pitr devas might not literally be your ancestors. And the shraddha offerings go to these pitra devatas. Shraddha is good because it saves these devatas from hell and gives them fruits. And in return they will help you in life.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Temporary heaven is rewarded for punya. Temporary hell is rewarded for sins. And yes, lower castes are allowed to drink liquor, eat garlic, etc.

Comment: Sir Thanks a lot for patient replies! Why will a Bramhana do Shardha for a Chandala?Vishnu Dharma Sastra(82.3-9) warns against Bramhanas who are Priests of Sudras and Chandalas! Then how would Sudras and Chandalas perform Shardhas and Marriages? Probably Shardha will be taught to Sudra Servant by Bramhana master but what about Marriage?
Sir Pitrs means our ancestors only

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Shraddha must be done for all. Manusmriti says that even asuras and rakshasas do shraddha, because all must satisfy their ancestors. That Vishnu Dharma verse prohibits Brahmanas from being full-time paid priests of shudras as a profession. It is also there in the manusmriti and commentator Medhatithi interprets it like that according to tradition. This is also necessary because elsewhere it says that shudras must perform shraddha. And there may be some parts of shraddha where mantras have to be uttered, and shudras can't utter those vedic mantras.

Comment: Oh sir so they would have Tantrik Shraddha? So Brahmana Priests do Marry and Do Shraddhas or teach to Sudras as per need right?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Something like that, I don't know exactly how yajnas are done for advijas. Some places, it says to do the same yajnas but without mantras. For example, for dvija women, the manusmriti says that all the sacraments (except marriage) must be done the same as for dvija men but without mantras. The same rule may apply to advijas. But regardless, if shudras can't perform a yajna, brahmana priests would do it on their behalf. And if they can't do a vedic yajna on their behalf, then they would do some agama/tantra yajna.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru And remember that the prohibition for being priests of shudras is in regard to being a full-time employed paid priest of a shudra.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Sir!!